# Entity-framework / Linq: How to left join while grouping into custom select?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have two tables that are not related using a foreign key but should be joinable. The relation (not FK) is one-to-many. Example:

```
Parent <- 1-to-many -> Child
```

1. I would like to **query** parents while joining children, even if they don't have children (left join?).
2. I would like to **select** a `parent` while manually setting the `children` property through some action

Sample:

```
    using(var context = new Test.Models.Ef.Entities())
    {
        var products = from p in context.Parent
                join c in context.Child on p.key equals c.parentkey
                select new {Parent = p, Child = c};
    }
```

Questions:

1. How do I "left join" the context.Child *table* in the above example?
2. How do I "group" the children by parent, while manually selecting it's children in a property?

   - Pseudo: `select p => p.Children = select c group by p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var products = from p in context.Parent
            join c in context.Child on p.key equals c.parentkey
            into pc select new { p, pc }
```

This executes a [GroupJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx), which translates to an outer join.

Comment: This seems to be going in the right direction. However `pc` is now an `IEnumerable<Child>`. How to I get the corresponding `Parent` in for instance a `foreach` loop?

Comment: The parent is in the `p`, and `pc` is a list of p's children. So you can loop through `products` and for each product.p you can loop through product.pc. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ok this makes it more clear. I guess my second question is more related to .NET syntax. I understand that `p` and `pc` are available in the `select` clause. How do I select `p` while setting `p.Children = pc` at the same time?

Comment: You could do that in the loop we discussed above. `product.p.Children = product.pc.ToList();`

Comment: Yes I understand I can do it in a loop, however I was hoping it would be possible in the `select` clausule in the linq query without another loop...?

Comment: I don't see how you could do that without doing some dirty tricks. Doing it in a loop is the best option I think.

Comment: A dirty trick would be: ... .ToList().Select(x => { x.p.Childeren.Clear(); foreach(var c in x.pc) x.p.Childern.Add(c); return x.p; }). But Select() is not meant to be used this way.